# What is the best method for receiving data from sensors through arduino board to android device?

Tags: android, arduino

I am developing one application for android which receives data from 13 different sensors through arduino adk board and display it on android device.I followed example of demokit but I have fear that it may loss the data because 13 sensors working together.I want to know what is the best method I can follow so that I'll not miss any byte of data or even lose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to lose any byte, then you must be constantly watching your sensors. A solution is to have two threads, one collecting the sensors data and putting it in a buffer of your own, and another reading from this buffer and processing the data.

Your question is about real-time performance, which means that you must test to see what are the optimal buffer sizes and data sizes to process for your application, while keeping timing correct on your specific hardware.

Comment: I think of making interrupt based like when arduino board receives sensors data it will send an interrupt signal to android device and according to that I can interprete that data, but I don't have any idea how to send interrupts to android device  from arduino and how to receive that interrupt in android device via usb bus.Is it a better way to communicate via USB?